# C - Static variable masking global variable

Tags: c, global-variables, static-variables

Have a look at the following code snippet...

File1.h

```
void somefunc(int);
```

File1.c

```
#include "File1.h"

extern int var;

void somefunc(int x)
{
   ......
   var ++;
   etc, etc,
   ....
   return;
}
```

File2.h

```
static int var;

void someotherfunc(int);
```

File2.c

```
#include "File2.h"
#include "File1.h"

int var;

void someotherfunc(int z)
{
   z = etc etc;
   var --;
   ......
   somefunc(z);
   .....
   return;
}
```

The above four files compile without any problem.
The problem occurs when i try to initialize the variable 'var'.
If the 'var' is initialized in the File2.c where it is a global variable, the code compiles without any problems. But when i try to initialize the static variable in File2.h, the compiler throws an error saying 'the variable 'var' in File1.c is undefined'. Can someone please tell what is happening here.

I was just trying to understand the concept of static variables and came upon this confusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do a "static int var;" in a header file? This will create one copy of static for each .c file in which you include this header file.

Comment: The header file is included by multiple files, thus violating the single definition rule. "You can declare anything as many times as you want, but you can only define it once."

Comment: That's not right, is it? `File2.h` (the one with the definition) is only included _once._ Or are you talking about the fact you define var in both that header and `File2.c`?

Comment: yes, exactly... the var is defined in both File2.c and .h... i know its not necessary.. but, i'm not looking for right or wrong here, i wanna know wat's happening in the code up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> static int var;

This gives `var` internal linkage in the File2.c translation unit, whatever might follow (yes, even if the `extern` declaration follows).

So if the first declaration seen is `static int var`, in that translation unit `var` will forever be internal, thus inaccessible to other translation units.

> 6.2.2-4
>
> For an identiﬁer declared with the storage-class speciﬁer `extern`
> [**`File1.h`**] in a scope in which a prior declaration of that
> identiﬁer is visible [**the one in File2.h**] if the prior declaration
> speciﬁes internal or external linkage [**it specifies internal**], the linkage of the identiﬁer at > the later declaration is **the same as the linkage speciﬁed at the
> prior declaration**.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be static. Static means its "visibility" (not the official term but probably more understandable) is limited to the C source file it appears in (in this case, that's `File2.c`).

That means, when you try to link together `File1` and `File2`, the linker will not be able to see `var` in `File2`, which is why you're getting the error.

If you want it accessible from `File1.c`, ditch the "static" bit. In fact, since you already have `var` defined in `File2.c`, ditch the entire line from `File2.h`.

Comment: Thanks!:)

I understand perfectly what you're trying to tell me. Yes, the static makes the visibility of 'var' internal to File2.c.

But wat is happening here is that, two seperate memory spaces are assigned for 'var'. One for the static variable and one for the global variable and program execution is also correct. But once I make an assignment to the static variable in File2.h as

static int var = 2; the compiler then throws an error saying "var in File1.c is undefined". I want to know what is exactly happening here and why?